# Eating with those who are eating and drinking haram

Tags: halal-haram, hadith, fiqh, practical-islam, hanafi

I live in a foster family of non-muslims/ non-mahrams and they eat haram and drink haram and I am a Muslim and they let us eat halal. But there are my two sisters and brother there too.

My question is if I sit with them and eat halal but they are eating haram and drinking haram (I am not eating haram), am I allowed to sit with them, is it haram or halal?
I think that I have heard a hadith about sitting with those who wine is being served to.
And if it is the case that I am not allowed to sit with them when they do that, does it apply to all haram meat (is there a hadith about sitting with those who are 'eating' haram)?

And what should I do if they do not allow me to follow the rulings of Islam?

Could you please quote some hadith with the exact source as well?

Answer (score 1):

بِسْمِ اللهِ الرَّحْمنِ الرَّحِيمِ

What haram is stays haram and for the opposite it's also true. As for sitting with those who drink alcohol it's disapproved to do it.

> Umar bin al-Khattab رضي الله عنه said: O people, I heard the Messenger
> of Allah ﷺ say: `Whoever believes in Allah and the Last Day, let him
> not sit at a table where alcohol is being passed around;
> Grade: Hasan lighairihi

Also if they serve you haram food you should refrain from eating it. And if they ask you why you are not eating you should state your religion and it's prohibition of it. If they don't allow you to practise your Deen then you should not listen to that and continue to fullfil it. But because of this they might not fully understand you, I can only advise you to stay patient with them and educate them in hopes they will understand and respect that. So if it's either between disobeying Allah or your foster family you should already know who takes that place.

It's also sad that you've landed in a foster family and i'd rather had seen you in a familt with similar values.

May Allah help you with your affairs and set them straight.